# How can I clear all data in a view and reload it?

Tags: ios, view

I have game that is played on a single view, when the game is over I want the user to be able to press a button (play again) that will completely reload the view (clearing all game data and refreshing the view as if it were loading for the first time). I have tried

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay]
```

however nothing is happening. Do I have to manually clear out the data or is there a way to reset everything at once?

Answer (score 0):

What I've similarly done in this case is to create a property which holds all of your game subviews,  etc.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *gameView;
```

Then in viewDidLoad, we call a method that sets up our game view for the first time (You will see we will use the same method a little later again for resetting the game)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setUpGame];
}

- (void)setUpGame
{
    // Your game views (subviews, buttons, etc.) set up here
    self.gameView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
}
```

Then, when the user taps the play again button, we simply remove the game view from the superview, and call the prior method we discussed, which sets up the game again. Your button's target should be set to call this method below: `[self playAgain];`

```
- (void)playAgain
{
    [self.gameView removeFromSuperview];

    // This is the method we previously discussed above
    [self setUpGame];
}
```

It's up to you to think of some cool and unique animations to make it a pleasing resetting of the game at this point :)

Answer (score 0):

setNeedsDisplay just indicates that you would like iOS to redraw the screen, which you rarely should need to call manually.

I would probably implement something like @troop231 already stated, which is a reset method, but I would not re-allocate any buttons / views etc because that could be costly. In the MVC model, you should have your data (scores, # of lives, etc.) stored separately and your views should just reference them. So, reset the model and assuming you have your views aware of model changes, they will update accordingly.

Ways to do this include KVO, NSNotification, Core Data's NSFetchedResultsController (probably overkill), delegation, etc.